# Java - Problema al recibir input text con este formato "%22USERMEX%22="

Tags: java, formato

tengo este problema en Java, que al recibir un input text del formulario para validar en un stored procedure, el valor del dato me lo da encerrado entre "%22" y "%22=" y no se como quitarle esto, ya que con este agregado no coincide la busqueda. No se si tenga que ver que uso una clase de apoyo como EasyUI...
Al debuguear el campo me indica que tiene el valor de "%22USERMEX%22=" cuando deberia ser solo "USERMEX"... alguien sabe que pasa?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar tu código?

Comment: seguramente te está llegando como si fuera ruta web revisa cómo recibes esos datos. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Bueno, elimine en parte el problema, lo que me colocaba los %22 era esto en el javascript:     
  data: valor,  
//data: JSON.stringify(valor),
Ahora me pone el USERMEX=  solo que no se ahora que es lo que le pone el signo de "="

Comment: Creo que puede ser por el encoding que hace HTML. %22 equivale a comillas ("). dependiendo del componente de visualización que estes usando la solución puede ser diferente.

Comment: Podrias entonces actualizar la pregunta para que se entienda cual es el problema que tenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el detalle, originalmente el script esta asi:

```
function checkExistEmpleado(valor) {
    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "checkExistEmpleado",
                cache : false,
                data: valor,
                dataType: 'text',
                context : document.body,
                success: function(data) {...etc
```

Pero me enviaba el valor con porcentaje(%22) y con signo de "=", entonces modifique el javascript y quedo así:

```
function checkExistEmpleado(valor) {
    $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : "checkExistEmpleado",
                cache : false,
                data: JSON.stringify(valor),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                context : document.body,
                success: function(data) {...etc
```

Y al fin envio el valor como se debe.

No era tanto de Java sino de cómo enviaba el valor por ajax.

Les agradezco mucho la ayuda, me guió a la idea de donde podría estar el problema.

Comment: Por favor recuerde **[aceptar su propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)**. Saludos.